# How can i get the top of the image of a tumblr post using tumblr tags?

Tags: facebook, tumblr

I want to set a OGP image url using tumblr tags like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{ANY TUMBLR TAG}"/>
```

I want to get top of the picture of the post which I created and set OGP image.

Does Anybody knows which tumblr tag should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tumblr should auto generate meta tags for Open Graph. However, to answer the question:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{block:Photo}{PhotoURL-250}{/block:Photo}"/>
```

You may need some template logic to make sure this is only printed on the PermalinkPage.

Comment: can this tag get the "top" picture of my post?

Comment: A photo post will only have one picture, so it would be the top one?

Comment: I want to get top picture of my "text" post.
I always insert photo of my text post.

Comment: @YusukeHigaki In that case, what you asking for isn't possible. In a `text` post, all the content for that post (images, text, links, etc) is returned in a single variable called `{Body}`. There is no logic to split this up sadly.

Comment: okay I understand. So, Do you know the logic which capture does tumblr choose as a thumbnail of facebook post. the last one?

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question. Facebook doesn't capture any images, you instruct Facebook with what image to use using `<meta property="og:image" ...`.